# Create a split zip file using Windows tools only? Not 7zip or similar

Tags: windows

Using Windows Standard tools only, is it possible to create a zip file and split it into different parts?

Not copying 7zip or some program onto the machine, Windows tools only.

Windows 7 x64

Comment: You can join fragments of a zip file using "copy /B", but the split operation does require an extra tool.

Comment: You might check Powershell here: http://ss64.com/ps/zip.html